# CI 3 doesn't receive any data from ajax, eventough it fires success

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

here's my ajax

```
        var data = {
            user_id : <?php echo $this->session->userdata('id') ?>,
            no_s0 : $('#no_so').val(),
            catatan : $('#remarks').val(),
            kode_barang : $('#kode_barang').val(),
            nama_toko : $('input[id="nama_toko"]').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get(),
            pcs : $('input[id="pcs"]').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get(),
            diskon : $('input[id="diskon"]').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get()
        }

$.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo base_url('sales_so/input') ?>',
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            error : function(){
                alert('gagal')
            },
            success : ()=>{
                alert('berhasil')
            }
        })
```

the status code is 200, and it worked fine. the problem is that i did not get any data from this. I tried to var_dump the data, but it give me this : array(0) { }

here's my controller :

```
$post = $this->input->post();
var_dump($post);
```

edit : please help, i still can't find the solution.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does your browser's network console show that the data has been submitted?

Comment: can you post your `var data` post data?

Comment: I tried to console.log(data). and yes, the data are there. but when send it with method post, somehow it doesn't receive any data. I've tried with serialize(). same, there is no data

Comment: As was already asked - have you confirmed in your browser's devtools that the data is really POSTed?  Click the network tab, and click the POST request to inspect it.  Maybe you need `dataType: "json"`?

Comment: yes, I cheked on network tab, click on the url. and yes I get a response like this :
array(7) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["no_so"]=>
  string(8) "90000000"
  ["catatan"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["kode_barang"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["nama_toko"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "pertama"
  }
  ["pcs"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["diskon"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}

Comment: if I use dataType : json. it will fire error callback function

Answer (score 1):

You can use serializeArray

`fields = $ ("#element").serializeArray();`

Comment: what element I need to apply that method?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you put this in your controller?

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump($post);
```

Comment: i got null.

honestly i still can't figure it out. I use get method instead of post. post method always  array(0) { } when try to var_dump. but when i check in network tools (in the browser) the data shows up. i still don't get it

Answer (score 0):

sorry about my english,

I assume the data you want to send comes from form submit, if true, it could be simple like this

```
var form = new FormData($("#id_form")[0]); // make sure to use the id on the form
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url:  <?php echo base_url('sales_so/input') ?>, 
data: form,  
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function(result){
    console.log(result); // for debugging can be seen on the console. or you can also use alert alert('sukses');
}
});
```

in controller try to var_dump the result

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Please translate all explanation to english